# Convert float with dictionary into new list

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have a dictionary and a float.

I like to replace the numbers in the float with the strings from the dictionary.

How can I do that?

```
 dictionary
Out[179]: 
{1: 'BaGr',
 2: 'OLF',
 3: 'MEDsr',
 4: 'MEDmr',
...
}

float
array([43., 3., 2., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not replace if float key is not availble in dict

```
for i in range(len(float)):
    float[i] = dictionary.get(int(float[i]), float[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data:

```
dd = {1: 'BaGr',
 2: 'OLF',
 3: 'MEDsr',
 4: 'MEDmr'
}

float_lst = [43., 3., 2., 0., 0., 4.]
```

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
print([dd.get(int(float_lst[i]), float_lst[i]) for i,x in enumerate(float_lst)])
```

Where:

```
dd.get(int(float_lst[i]), float_lst[i])
```

means, get the value from the dict `dd` of the `int` converted elem from the list `int(float_lst[i])`, if no value from the dict is found, print the elem of the list by default i.e. `float_lst[i]`.

OUTPUT:

```
[43.0, 'MEDsr', 'OLF', 0.0, 0.0, 'MEDmr']
```